# Maven: use common/shared plugins when working with multiple profiles

Tags: maven-2

I have a project that is using several profiles. Each profile uses following plugins:

- maven-compiler-plugin
- maven-resources-plugin
- **maven-antrun-plugin**
- maven-surefire-plugin
- maven-war-plugin

The one marked in bold is however the only plugin where there is a difference between the profiles (different configuration files will be copied using the antrun plugin). The 4 other plugins are configured exactly the same for all profiles.

The question is now: is there some way to include these common plugins only once but still use them for all the profiles by default?

Something like:

`<shared><plugin1><plugin2>...</shared>`
`<profile><plugin3></profile>`
`<profile><plugin3></profile>`
...

thanks,
Stijn

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a plugin is used by all profile, simply define it in the `<build>` part :

```
<project>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
             Your shared plugins go here...
        </plugins>

    <profiles>
        Definition of profiles...
    </profiles>
</project>
```

This way, you will only define the antrun plugin in the `profiles` block.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply; this is what a trief first (few days ago) but then it gave me build errors. I tried it again and now it seems to work fine so apparently the errors had a different cause.

Answer (score 10):

Just include the common plugins in your `build` section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then add the specific plugin in your profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>...</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>...</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plugin3</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You can also configure the same plugin differently in different profiles this way:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>...</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <setting>value1</setting>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>...</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <setting>value2</setting>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: is there no way to have a common build > plugins > plugin that can be reused by multiple profiles to reduce the redundancy?
My goal is it to run a plugin before build for local development and for integration tests on my CI/CD